# How to build a query with the AND operator?

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot execute queries with the operator "AND" either with filters or the query.

I've read:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/

I have tried:

```
'curl -XGET url_local:9200/chasseur_de_tete/cv/_search -d ' { 
"filtered" : { 
  "query" : { 
    "match_all" : {} },
      "filter" : { 
        "and" : { 
          "filters" : [
            {"term" : {"active" : true }},
            { "term" : { "deleted" : false }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
} '
```

That produces the following error:

```
{
    "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[9Fx2f7-MSNyYATEMPgemLw][chasseur_de_tete][4]: SearchParseException[[chasseur_de_tete][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { \"filtered\" : { \"query\" : { \"match_all\" : {} }, \"filter\" : { \"and\" : { \"filters\" : [{ \"term\" : { \"active\" : \"true\" }},{ \"term\" : { \"deleted\" : \"false\" }}] } }}} ]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[chasseur_de_tete][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [filtered]]]; }{[9Fx2f7-MSNyYATEMPgemLw][chasseur_de_tete][3]: SearchParseException[[chasseur_de_tete][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [ { \"filtered\" : { \"query\" : { \"match_all\" : {} }, \"filter\" : { \"and\" : { \"filters\" : [{ \"term\" : { \"active\" : \"true\" }},{ \"term\" : { \"deleted\" : \"false\" }}] } }}} ]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[chasseur_de_tete][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [filtered]]]; }]",
    "status": 500
}
```

I have also tried:

```
`curl url_local:9200/chasseur_de_tete/joboffer/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
         {"term":{"active":"false"}},
         {"term":{"deleted":"true"}}
      ] 
    } 
  }
} '
```

This query does not return an error message, but it returns all records of my collection.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "active": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "deleted": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to POST it in the request body.

Comment: Thanks, the problem cames from I use GET method